# MacTex not installing

Tags: installing, mactex

I clean-installed Mavericks and now tried to install MacTex.

I tried
 1. downloading the MacTeX.pkg from http://www.tug.org/mactex/index.html
 2. downloading from mirrors [http://www.tug.org/mactex/mirrorpage.html]
 3. using Safari 7 and Safari 5.
 4. changing permissions and ownership [me: read & write, me: owner]

I always get:
Installer:
"The Installer is damaged.
The Installer can’t open the package. There may be a problem with file ownership or permissions."
Installer log:
"Dec  3 14:42:24 Js-MacBook-Pro.local Installer[782]: Install's runner tool is not properly configured as a setuid tool.
Dec  3 14:42:24 Js-MacBook-Pro.local Installer[782]: Unable to create InstallController"

None of the related threads could help me.

Comment: This sounds like a problem related to the MacOSX installer app, rather than something caused by MacTeX. Have you considered posting this query to apple.stackexchange.com?

Comment: This is a rare occasion where using Disk Utility to fix permissions might help, if runner is actually not configured setuid. `$ ls -l /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Install.framework/Versions/A/Resources/runner
-rwsr-sr-x  1 root  wheel  120320 Sep 24 15:55 /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/Install.framework/Versions/A/Resources/runner*`